# Let $(Y,\rho)$ be a metric space and $\rho : Y \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Prove that $\rho$ is a continuous function on $Y \times Y$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(Y,d)$ be a metric space and $d : Y \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Prove that $d$ is a continuous function on $Y \times Y$.

I was thinking of the following :

If $(a_{1},a_{2}) \in Y \times Y$, and $(b_{1},b_{2}) \in Y \times Y$, then $d^{(p)}((a_{1},a_{2}), (b_{1}, b_{2})) = ||d(a_{1}, b_{1}), d(a_{2},b_{2})||_{p}$.

From here I am unsure. It was just an idea though. I would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 2 points $(y_1,y_2)$ and $(y_3,y_4)$ in $Y\times Y$. Then
$$
|d(y_1,y_2)-d(y_3,y_4)|=|d(y_1,y_2)+d(y_2,y_3)-(d(y_2,y_3)+d(y_3,y_4))|\\
\leq|d(y_1,y_2)+d(y_2,y_3)|+|d(y_2,y_3)+d(y_3,y_4)|\\
=d(y_1,y_2)+d(y_2,y_3)+d(y_2,y_3)+d(y_3,y_4)\leq d(y_1,y_3)+d(y_2,y_4).
$$
Now you can use the inequalities
$$
(a+b)^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2)\implies a+b\leq|a+b|\leq\sqrt{2}[a^2+b^2]^{1/2}
$$
and a standard $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument to complete the claim.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$|d(x,y)-d(w,z)|\leqslant d(x,w)+d(y,z)$$

But the product topology in $Y\times Y$ is metrizable by $d_\pi((x,y),(x',y'))=d(x,x')+d(y,y')$, so we're done.

Comment: Makes sense. If I wanted to use this idea in conjunction with some epsilon delta proof what would that look like?